# How to separate multiple-character values inside row?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have this dummy input dataframe. (Input dataframe cannot be changed)

```
data <- data.frame(c('c(a1, a10)'),
                   c('c(b1, b10)'),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(data) <- c('A', 'B')
head(data)
#           A          B
#1 c(a1, a10) c(b1, b10)
```

And I would like to turn this dataframe to below dataframe. *Tidyverse*, *dplyr* approach will be helpful.

```
#    A            B
#1  a1           b1
#2 a10          b10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove additional text around the character and use `separate_rows`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~gsub('c\\(|\\)', '', .))) %>%
  separate_rows(A:B, sep = ',\\s*')

#  A     B    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a1    b1   
#2 a10   b10
```

Comment: I applied this code to larger dataframe but it shows error "Error: In row 1, can't recycle input of size 327 to size 334". how to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: @choij Provide example input data that would reproduce your error. I am guessing you are getting this error because number of items differ, e.g.: `data <- data.frame(c('c(a1, a10, a11)'), c('c(b1, b10)'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the **`tidyr`** library's function named `separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(t(apply(data, 1, function(x) gsub("c\\(|\\)", "", x)))) %>% 
  separate_rows(colnames(.), sep=',\\s*')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  A     B    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a1    b1   
2 a10   b10
```

This only requires the `tidyr` library, and it doesn't need the `dplyr` package.

**Explanation:**

It applies on every a function with removes the `c(` in the beginning and `)` at the end with regex in the function `gsub`. Then applies the `tidyr::separate_rows` function on all the column names (with `colnames(.)`), and specified the separator as a regex `,\\s*`, which is a comma and a space.

Comment: I applied this code to larger dataframe, but it says "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `column1`, `column2`, etc. don't exist.  But that input dataframe already have column which is column1 and column2. thank you

Comment: @choij Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can first `str_extract` the relevant strings using lookbehind and lookahead and then `separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
  mutate(across(c(1:2), 
                ~str_extract_all(., "(?<=\\()[^,\\s]+|[^,\\s]+(?=\\))"))) %>% 
  separate_rows(., sep = ",\\s*") %>%
  unnest(cols = c(1:2))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  A     B    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a1    b1   
2 a10   b10
```